# Disable Checkboxes in Sencha Touch

Tags: iphone, ipad, html, sencha-touch

I am trying to use the Check Box makes the component greyout/ disable.

```
field.setDisabled(true);
```

This works fine in browser, but in iPhone and iPad devices browser it is disabling and gray out the label but still user us be able to select any of the checkboxes.

Does anybody know how to implement this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably due to opened [BUG #135 (Disabled Checkboxes/Radiobuttons still working)](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?134825).

Comments to bug provide couple of workarounds one of which is (you can put this in one of your JavaScript files elsewhere after Sencha Touch is loaded, you should require `Ext.form.Checkbox` first if it not yet exists too):

```
Ext.override(Ext.form.Checkbox, {
  onChange: function(e) {
    if (e) {
      if (e.browserEvent) {
        e = e.browserEvent;
      }

      if (Ext.supports.Touch && !e.isSimulated) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        return;
      }
    }

    if(!this.isDisabled()){
      if (this.isChecked()) {
        this.lastState = true;
        this.fireEvent('check', this);
      } else {
        this.lastState = false;
        this.fireEvent('uncheck', this);
      }
    } else {
      var state;
      if(!Ext.isEmpty(this.lastState)){
        state = this.lastState;
      } else {
        state = Ext.isEmpty(this.originalState) ?
                  this.getBooleanIsChecked(this.checked) : this.originalState;
      }
      this.setChecked(state);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: I could find the bug and the comments, but workarounds are looks much more complicated to understand. May be as i am beginner to sencha. Can you please help me to understand any easy fix for it.

Comment: I have put the code inside launch function of Ext.Application. But still its not working. I am using sencha touch1

Comment: Overriding this also not fixing the issue.